# Using Same s3 instance ( "aws-sdk" ) with varying the credentials on each request

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, design-patterns, aws-sdk, multi-tenant

The case :

- I have multi-tenant system, and each tenant has his bucket and accessKeyId and accessSecret, and I am creating a wrapper above AWS.S3 to extend some functionality.

Can i use same instance of s3 client but alter the credentials based on the requesting user credentials?

Like this :

```
class S3Storage {
 private readonly s3: AWS.S3;

 constructor(config: S3Config) {
     this.s3 = new AWS.S3({
       accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
       secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,
       apiVersion: config.apiVersion,
       region: config.region
     });
   }

 public myDownload (key: string, userData: any) {
  // alter credentials for this.s3 with the userData
 }
}
```

Or should i create s3 client (with provided userData) every time `myDownload` function is invoked.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to create one ```AWS.S3``` object per credential set. If necessary you could try to cache the credentials inside some property of the class to avoid creating the object every time.

Comment: Would not that cause any problem in server's memory (for many reqs), cuz i think the `AWS.S3` object per function won't be removed from memory after function stack is removed (because i think objects are heap allocated in javascript ??? ) @JCOlivares

Comment: If you cache these objects, it's certainly possible that they could cause an issue. You will have to evaluate if just creating a new object every time works better for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating S3 client per request rather than caching already cached objects because on each request the system gets a temporarily generated   credentials.